# Call from ios app with Pause

Tags: ios, voip, phone-call, tel, telprompt

I am working with VOIP application. I am trying to make call from my **ios app** which contains Pauses indicated with (,).

```
      NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:finalNumber];
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

On dialling number, call is not connected. What I can use to allow pause in my number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **`tel://`** scheme:

Objective-C

```
NSString *telUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@,%@", contactPhone, contactExtension];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:telUrl]];
```

Swift

```
    let formattedPhone = "tel://\(contactPhone),\(contactExtension)"
    if let phoneURL = NSURL(string:formattedPhone) {
        print(phoneURL)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(phoneURL)
    }
```

And make sure your string doesn't have white spaces.

Cheers.